# How do I solve __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, redux-toolkit

I am trying to use the token from my redux store inside my Axios instance. I tried importing the store but I am getting the and error saying `_app_store__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default is undefined`. Please how do I solve this?

This is my code.

> store.js

```
    import { configureStore, combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
    import authReducer from "../features/auth/authSlice";
    import cartReducer from "../features/cart/cartSlice";
    
    import {
      persistReducer,
      FLUSH,
      REHYDRATE,
      PAUSE,
      PERSIST,
      PURGE,
      REGISTER,
    } from "redux-persist";
    import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
    
    const persistConfig = {
      key: "root",
      storage,
    };
    
    const reducers = combineReducers({
      auth: authReducer,
      cart: cartReducer,
    });
    
    const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);
    
    const store = configureStore({
      reducer: persistedReducer,
      middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware({
          serializableCheck: {
            ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
          },
        }),
    });
    
    export default store;
```

Then this is my axios instance file.

> api.js

```
    import axios from "axios";
    import store from "../app/store";
    
    const token = store.getState().auth.token;
    
    const api = axios.create({
      baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
      headers: {
        Authorization: token,
      },
    });
    
    export default api;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I was trying to use the store before it was initialized. So I just created an interceptor for the Axios instance and called the store in there.

> api.js

```
    import axios from "axios";
    import store from "../app/store";
    
    const api = axios.create({
      baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
    });
    
    api.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
      const token = store.getState().auth.token;
      config.headers = {
        Authorization: token ? `Bearer: ${token}` : null,
      };
      return config;
    });
    
    export default api;
```